# How to allow `gitolite writable` to everyone?

Tags: git

I want for clients to be able to lock any branch (or at leas repository) to which they have write control. `gitolite writable off` seems to do just that. But I can't grasp the permissions.

```
$ ssh git@192.168.56.1 writable testing off
FATAL: you are not authorized
```

How can ordinary users be authorized to do this? The client already has their public key in `gitolite-admin/keydir` and has RW+ permissions on `testing`.

Answer (score 1):

So the source is the best documentation, as a colleague used to say.

```
gitolite/src/commands/writable:
_die "you are not authorized" if $ENV{GL_USER} and not( owns($repo) or is_admin() or ( can_write($repo) and $op eq 'status' ) );
```

So, in order to lock writes to a repo, one needs to either be the admin, or to own the repo. What does owning the repo mean?

```
src/lib/Gitolite/Easy.pm:
return ( creator($r) eq $user or $rc{OWNER_ROLENAME} and in_role( $rc{OWNER_ROLENAME}, $r ) );
```

So we must have either created the repo (not feasible) or be listed in `gitolite-admin/conf/gitolite.conf` as owner.

- How do we register *all* users as owners?
- Does this create some security vulnerability?

Aaand that's how far I am now. `$ find gitolite | xargs grep OWNER_ROLENAME` returns that this string is never mentioned in another file plus I don't speak pearl :(

Furthermore, `/home/git/.gitolite.rc` lists only two roles `READERS` and `WRITERS`.